# Predefining C Array

Tags: c, arrays

In C, when defining an array I can do the following:

```
int arr[] = {5, 2, 9, 8};
```

And thus I defined it and filled it up, but how do I define it in my .h file, and then fill it in my .c?

Like do something like

```
int arr[];
arr = {5, 2, 9, 8};
```

I'm pretty new to C, not sure how it would look

any suggestions?

Comment: What is the purpose of defining it in a .h and then declaring it in the .c?  If you only have one .c, just define/declare it there.  If you need it shared between .c files - mention that in your question too (only for clarity, it was assumed by some who answered the question already)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, you'd put:

```
extern int arr[];
```

In the .h file, and:

```
int arr[] = { 5, 2, 9, 8};
```

In the .c file.

Edit: Dale Hagglund and KevinDTimm raise good points: you only want to put the initialization in *one* .c file, and you only need to put *anything* in the .h file if you're going to access `arr` from code in more than one .c file.

Comment: If your program has multiple C files, make sure that only one defines the array, that is, contains the second line above.  The rest only need to declare it by including the `.h` file containing `extern int arr[];`

Comment: I would question the need to define in the .h at all, unless there is a sharing occurring.  Maybe point the OP in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use include guards to prevent the assignemnt from happening multiple times, but putting the assignment into headers is a very bad practice in my opinion.  Put the intialization in a c file, in an init function instead and extern the array in the h file.